# JPA with EclipseLink: Decoding charset issue

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, eclipselink

Im using JPA with EclipseLink to connect to my mySQL db. I am writing utf-8 text and i can validate that it's being written with the correct encoding by querying the data from MySQL Workbench. But, when i retrieve the data from my java console app, the encoding is incorrect.

I've tried adding characterEncoding to my connection url, but no luck!

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb?useUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;characterSetResults=UTF-8&amp;"/>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: In order to get some help, you are going to have to include the code that is performing the data retrieval. And what is the data encoding that is returned by the console application?

Answer (score 0):

My DB's datatype was JSON, so I changed it to *mediumtext CHARSET utf8* and it worked i.e. I got back the data with the right encoding. From MySQL's [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html) json datatype is saved in utf8mb4 so i still do not know why would it not work with the JSON datatype. Additionally, i do  not think this is an issue with mysql, as I can read the data in Workbench and it has the right encoding. My only guess is that since JSON datatypes are fairly new there a bug with the mysql/JPA integration.